# Footer div won't stay down when expanding GridView

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, footer

I have this page in which I have a footer, the page also displays a Gridview, the contents of the Gridview depend on what the user selects, the Gridview may have from nothing, to 168 rows, and everything in between.

The master page is like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  STUFF
  <div id="footer">
    <p>This is the footer</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The CSS is like this:

```
#footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 background: #E1E1E1;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
}
```

Now, I have tried position:fixed, but it's not what I want, that way the footer displays over the content of the page, I want it to be at the bottom. If I set it to relative it sets to the bettom of the content place holder of the master page, but you can still see it behind the Gridviews, if I set it to absolute, it goes to the bottom, but it only works when the Gridview has a certain small size of rows, if it has to display many rows, the footer will appear behind the gridviews as well.

This is driving me crazy. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: why don't you use `<table></table>` to organize your page content?!

Comment: you have `>` missing in `</body`

Comment: That was a typo, I made that code up just to show where the footer was located.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
[Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```